# How to pass an array to display it in an html file? - Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm currently working on a project and having some issues with my code ..

My problem: My node.js is analysing a txt file and reading coordinates out of it .. those coordinates should be displayed in a graph in an html file .. both codes are created, but how do I connect them?

node.js:

```
    var fs = require('fs');


function readLines(input, done) {
    var arr = [];
    var remaining = '';

    input.on('data', function(data) {
        remaining += data;
        var index = remaining.indexOf('\n');
        while (index > -1) {
            var line = remaining.substring(0, index);
            remaining = remaining.substring(index + 1);
            func(line);
            index = remaining.indexOf('\n');
        }
    });

    input.on('end', function() {
        if (remaining.length > 0) {
            func(remaining);
            done(arr);
        }
    });

    function func(data) {
        arr.push(data.split(/\s+/g)); //Splitfunktion für Komma 
    }
}


var input = fs.createReadStream('test.txt');
readLines(input, done);

//abschließen 
function done(arr) {

    var obj = {};
    var key1 = arr[0][0];
    var key2 = arr[0][1];
    obj[key1] = [];
    obj[key2] = [];

    arr.shift();

    arr.forEach(function (item) {
        obj[key1].push(item[0]);
        obj[key2].push(item[1]);
    });

    console.log('X:', obj[key1]);
    console.log('Y:', obj[key2])
}
```

Html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head> 
    <!-- ... --> 
    </head>
    <body>  
     <!-- ..... --> 
    <script>
        var lineChartData = {
            labels : [380, 390 ..<!--  X-Coordinates here --> 
            datasets : [
                {
                    data : [0.5, 
                            0.6, 
                            0.7,  
                            <!-- Y-Coordinates here --> 
                            ]
                }
            ]

        }

    <!-- ... ---> 
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help!

Greetings,

JS

Comment: I think you should look into [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use expressjs. Using `nodejs` to create web application is quite low-level. You have to install express via node `npm install express` and go from there.

**Some code snipped to help**

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.register('.html', require('ejs'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    // Handle file reading in here and return object
    res.render('index.html', {obj: obj}); //where object is the obj is the object holding the arrays
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});
```

**then in your index.html do .. inside script tags.**

```
<script>
    console.log(<%= cordinates.obj %>);
</script>
```

DISCLAIMER: I haven't tested this but it's just to help you on your way

Comment: Hi dcodesmith, that already helped a lot! What do you mean with {coordinates: obj} ?  -> obj[key1] and obj[key2] are both the X and Y coordinates .. Do you have an idea how to send them separately to the index.html?

Comment: You don't need to send them separately, you could just access them in the html.

Comment: Alright, server is starting without errors and it works, but when I look at the sourcecode of the html file, I see at the point, where I put the console.log(<%= cordinates.obj %>):  console.log(undefined); .. Any idea?

Comment: try console.log('<%= cordinates.obj %>'):

Comment: It tells me that cordinates is not defined ..any idea?

Comment: console.log('<%= obj %>')